# Jquery validation on modal popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have found a few topics on this matter, but none of them fits my needs, or solves my problem.
So this is the on the main page:

```
<div id="contentDiv">
    <div style="margin-top: -31px;">
        <form>
            <table class="tableFormLayout" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" id="openOrderItemAddPopup" value="Add" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>    
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Orders/OrderItemAddPopup.cshtml", Model)            
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And this in the popup:

```
@model MvcAppMobileJQuery.ViewModels.OrderVM

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div data-role="none" id="OrderItemAddPopup" data-overlay-theme="b" style="width: 500px;"
    class="ui-corner-all">
    <div data-role="content">

        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <form id="#orderitemsform">
            <table class="tableFormLayout" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Quantity, new {@class = "label"})
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity, new {data_mini = "true", type = "number", id = "txtQuantity"})
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="button" id="load" data-inline="true" value="Save" data-icon="forward"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#load').click(function () {
        $('#orderitemsform').validate();

        if ($('#orderitemsform').valid()) {
            alert("valid");
        }
        else {
            alert("invalid");
        }
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#OrderItemAddPopup').modalPopLite({ openButton: '#openOrderItemAddPopup', closeButton: '#closeOrderItemAddPopup', isModal: true });
    });
</script>
```

And the viewmodel:

```
public class OrderVM
{
    [DisplayName("Quantiy")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity is required")]
    [RegularExpression("^[1-9]\\d*$", ErrorMessage = "Quantity must be positive")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I an error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined`

If I change this:

```
$("#orderitemsform").validate();
if ($("#orderitemsform").valid()) {
```

to this:

```
$('form').validate();
if ($('form').valid()) {
```

it works, but it also validates the form on the main window, which I don't want at this point.

Comment: Why are you using the form tag in the main page?

Comment: @Sharun I have this issue on a bigger project, these are only some bits I put together on a dummy project to reproduce the issue. And I actually use @Html.BeginForm(smth...) on my project, but I made it like this to reproduce it as accurate as possible.

Comment: Do you really need to put the second form inside the main form?

Comment: And also try moving `@Html.ValidationSummary()` to inside of the form tag

Comment: I didn't need until I had to validate some inputs. The popup doesn't submit, it loads a partial on the main view. So as far as I read, to do this kind of validation, I need a form

Comment: Try removing form tag in the main page

Comment: I did, doesn't work. and I would have needed the form on the main view anyway...

Comment: You said you are using @html.beginform; did you include the id as well as name parameters for the form?

Comment: this is how the original looks like: @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveOrder", "Orders")).  I have tried adding an id to this form on the test project and it didn't work

Comment: Try this: `@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveOrder", "Orders", FormMethod.Post, new { id="orderitemsform", name="orderitemsform"})) {..}`

Comment: you mean on the popup? the beginform I sent you was from the main window. on the popup I don't want to submit the form

Comment: I can't understand your problem. If you dont need to submit it why are you using a form?

Comment: And even if you dont want to submit the form, you can still use html.beginform.

Comment: Since Mvc 4, there is no need for Html.BeginForm() anymore, it can be replaced with a html form. And I need the form to perform the jquery validation.

Comment: You can always use form tag or other basic html controls in you view. But I wont say that is a good method.

Comment: And I am still unable to understand what you are trying to achieve here. I would have simply used a form outside the main form, as you said it doesn't need to be posted.

Comment: it needs to be posted, doesn't need to be submited...what I am doing is on the main form I have a few inputs, like the order details, then I am adding to the page some order items from the popup. On the save of the popup I post with ajax some values to an action which returns a partial view as string in a json result, then get the json and attach it to a div; this way I load on the page some partials with the order items, at the end of the process I submit the main form and save the order with the order items that I added from the popup. This thatI posted is only a dummy to make it work

Comment: so I guess what I am trying to achieve is not so important. Just how to make this work with the controls that are on it now. and I can't make it work...

Comment: Ok. So as I said you need not include the second form inside the mainform. Try putting ` @Html.Partial("~/Views/Orders/OrderItemAddPopup.cshtml", Model)` outside main form

Comment: I managed to make it, this helped, together with an answer that has disappeared, but was not right, just gave me the idea. So I will put up the solution. Thanks

Comment: I have voted your two comments that helped so that they can be noticed. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Change the button at the last of your form to input type `Submit` as the unobtrusive validation will fire while trying to submit the form.

also make sure that

```
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

these keys are present in the web config. and the all the required scripts are loaded before the loading of form.

Check the bundle 
`@section Scripts {
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        }`
has been renderd.

Comment: as was discussed in the comments above, I don't submit that form.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
<div id="contentDiv">
    <div style="margin-top: -31px;">
        <form>
            <table class="tableFormLayout" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" id="openOrderItemAddPopup" value="Add" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <div id="mydiv">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Orders/OrderItemAddPopup.cshtml", Model)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

inside the popup:

```
 <form id="#orderitemsform">
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <table class="tableFormLayout" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Quantity, new {@class = "label"})
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity, new {data_mini = "true", type = "number", id = "txtQuantity"})
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="button" id="load" data-inline="true" value="Save" data-icon="forward"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

and the script:

```
$('#load').click(function () {
    $("#mydiv form").validate(); if ($("#mydiv form").valid()) {
        alert("valid");
    }
    else {
        alert("invalid");
    }
});
```